# Ansible plugin gc_storage

Tags: ansible, google-cloud-storage

i use ansible plugin gc_storage to create bucket and upload some file to bucket.
im refer from here [ansible gc_storage plugin](https://docs.ansible.com/archive/ansible/2.5/modules/gc_storage_module.html)

im trying to use "**get**" action and it seems good, job is running well. but every i try using action "**put**" or "**create**" i always get error.

```
    The full traceback is:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/fun/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1689656450.9087405-53-176146873251438/AnsiballZ_gc_storage.py", line 107, in <module>
    _ansiballz_main()
  File "/home/fun/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1689656450.9087405-53-176146873251438/AnsiballZ_gc_storage.py", line 99, in _ansiballz_main
    invoke_module(zipped_mod, temp_path, ANSIBALLZ_PARAMS)
  File "/home/fun/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1689656450.9087405-53-176146873251438/AnsiballZ_gc_storage.py", line 48, in invoke_module
    run_name='__main__', alter_sys=True)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/runpy.py", line 205, in run_module
    return _run_module_code(code, init_globals, run_name, mod_spec)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/runpy.py", line 96, in _run_module_code
    mod_name, mod_spec, pkg_name, script_name)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/tmp/ansible_gc_storage_payload_08k25v0c/ansible_gc_storage_payload.zip/ansible_collections/community/google/plugins/modules/gc_storage.py", line 497, in <module>
  File "/tmp/ansible_gc_storage_payload_08k25v0c/ansible_gc_storage_payload.zip/ansible_collections/community/google/plugins/modules/gc_storage.py", line 474, in main
  File "/tmp/ansible_gc_storage_payload_08k25v0c/ansible_gc_storage_payload.zip/ansible_collections/community/google/plugins/modules/gc_storage.py", line 408, in handle_create
  File "/tmp/ansible_gc_storage_payload_08k25v0c/ansible_gc_storage_payload.zip/ansible_collections/community/google/plugins/modules/gc_storage.py", line 228, in create_bucket
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/boto/gs/connection.py", line 95, in create_bucket
    data=get_utf8_value(data))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/boto/s3/connection.py", line 659, in make_request
    auth_path = self.calling_format.build_auth_path(bucket, key)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/boto/s3/connection.py", line 94, in build_auth_path
    path = '/' + bucket
TypeError: must be str, not bytes
fatal: [192.167.21.2]: FAILED! => {
    "changed": false,
    "module_stderr": "Shared connection to 192.167.21.2 closed.\r\n",
    "module_stdout": "Traceback (most recent call last):\r\n  File \"/home/fun/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1689656450.9087405-53-176146873251438/AnsiballZ_gc_storage.py\", line 107, in <module>\r\n    _ansiballz_main()\r\n  File \"/home/fun/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1689656450.9087405-53-176146873251438/AnsiballZ_gc_storage.py\", line 99, in _ansiballz_main\r\n    invoke_module(zipped_mod, temp_path, ANSIBALLZ_PARAMS)\r\n  File \"/home/fun/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1689656450.9087405-53-176146873251438/AnsiballZ_gc_storage.py\", line 48, in invoke_module\r\n    run_name='__main__', alter_sys=True)\r\n  File \"/usr/lib64/python3.6/runpy.py\", line 205, in run_module\r\n    return _run_module_code(code, init_globals, run_name, mod_spec)\r\n  File \"/usr/lib64/python3.6/runpy.py\", line 96, in _run_module_code\r\n    mod_name, mod_spec, pkg_name, script_name)\r\n  File \"/usr/lib64/python3.6/runpy.py\", line 85, in _run_code\r\n    exec(code, run_globals)\r\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_gc_storage_payload_08k25v0c/ansible_gc_storage_payload.zip/ansible_collections/community/google/plugins/modules/gc_storage.py\", line 497, in <module>\r\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_gc_storage_payload_08k25v0c/ansible_gc_storage_payload.zip/ansible_collections/community/google/plugins/modules/gc_storage.py\", line 474, in main\r\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_gc_storage_payload_08k25v0c/ansible_gc_storage_payload.zip/ansible_collections/community/google/plugins/modules/gc_storage.py\", line 408, in handle_create\r\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_gc_storage_payload_08k25v0c/ansible_gc_storage_payload.zip/ansible_collections/community/google/plugins/modules/gc_storage.py\", line 228, in create_bucket\r\n  File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/boto/gs/connection.py\", line 95, in create_bucket\r\n    data=get_utf8_value(data))\r\n  File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/boto/s3/connection.py\", line 659, in make_request\r\n    auth_path = self.calling_format.build_auth_path(bucket, key)\r\n  File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/boto/s3/connection.py\", line 94, in build_auth_path\r\n    path = '/' + bucket\r\nTypeError: must be str, not bytes\r\n",
    "msg": "MODULE FAILURE\nSee stdout/stderr for the exact error",
    "rc": 1
}
```

is there anything i miss from the setup ?

Comment: And what does the task causing this stack trace looks like? (You should add that piece of information in an [edit] of your question).